# Textarea validation

Tags: php, html

My script is supposed not to let the HTML form be submitted unless a user enters some data into a textarea control. However, the form gets submitted anyway and no message for the user is displayed.
Could anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my HTML:

```
<textarea name="description" id="description" rows = "4" cols = "25">
    <?php echo $description?>
    </textarea>
```

As for PHP, neither this:

```
if ($_POST['description'] == "") {
            $errors .= 'Please enter a description of your invention.<br/><br/>';
        }
```

or this:

```
if (empty($_POST['description'])) {
            $errors .= 'Please enter a description of your invention.<br/><br/>';
        }
```

work.

Comment: Post the full script with relevant parts

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because the text area isn't empty! Note that you're putting a tab before <?php echo $description?>, which means at the very least the text area will always contain a tab.

Change your validation code to something like this:

```
if (trim($_POST['description']) == "") {
```

Comment: Actually your text area probably contains a newline, a tab, and another new line.

Comment: Yeah, either remove the whitespace completely, or trim it on the way into the database, otherwise every time you edit the description it's going to gain more and more leading/trailing whitespace. (Note also you need `htmlspecialchars()` over the `$description` to avoid HTML-injection leading to potential XSS security problems.)

Comment: @bobince Good call on mentioning the use of htmlspecialchars.

Comment: @bobince - Thank you htmlspecialchars().
It's a very good point. I'm going to use it.

Answer (score 0):

In your form put:

```
<form onsubmit = "return checkSubmit()">
```

Then in your Javascript somewhere:

```
function checkSubmit(){
  if (form good)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

Comment: dangerous, never trust on client side validation alone!

Answer (score 0):

You have some white space between the `<textarea>` tags. Have you tried outputting `$_POST['description']` to see if this is being posted back? The extra new lines may be messing it up. You can try adding a minimum length to it.